# MySQL WorkBench doesn't work, but in the Task Manager it's running

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL WorkBench to connect it to NodeJS. When I try to do it, it gives me an error and I stop the MySQL server. When I start it again, the MySQL WorkBench doesn't open, but I look the Task Manager the WorkBench is running. What can I do to can open the WorkBench again?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How can you connect MySQL Workbench to Node.js? Node.js is a Javascript runtime, while MySQL Workbench is a MySQL client tool. The two have nothing in common. You can connect to a MySQL server only, with WB.

It could be that the application binary hangs on some input it cannot deal with. It **should** usually just error out, but things go weird at times. So, when you see a Workbench process in the task list, but no indication that Workbench is still active (on the desktop) then use the task manager to kill that process.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I ask the cuestión bad. The conexión to MySQL was only yo MySQL, but I wanted to use the WorkBench at the dame time. I restarted my computer and it works.